# Ignoring empty <p> tags in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i am currently trying to program a little **scraper** in python to build a worlist, using the wikipedia random url to search the most pages with different words, and im actually having a problem making it ignore empty `<p></p>` tags and making the function query the url another time after it goes threw the inital loop.

Sorry for the Crappy code but i am very very new to programming and python and i am self taught so sorry for eventual facepalm moments. :P

here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def wiki_spider():
    value = 1
    wordlist = open("wordlist.txt","w")
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
    while value == 1:
            sourcepage = requests.get(url)
            plaintext = sourcepage.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
            for words in soup.findAll('p'):
                word = words.string
                ##if word == "\n":
                   ##wordlist.write("")
                ##wordlist.write(word)
                print(word)
    start()

def start():
    wiki_spider()

start()
```

thanks for all you input.

Comment: I see a while loop, and then I see start calling wiki_spider which in turn calls start into oblivion. What is the thinking/intention behind that?

Comment: im trying to make the function wiki_spider() call back to start() again when its done going threw the page. but this method is obviously not working.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're doing, and having methods call each other in an infinite loop like that probably isn't the best idea as there might not be a good way to stop the loop. That's what `while`/`for` (native) looping methods are for.

Comment: So just so I make sure I understand your question, it appears these are your two problems that you need answered: 1) how to make queries in a loop, 2) how to ignore empty `<p>` tags. Is that it?

Comment: alright, thanks for that input. and what about the the html <p> tags, they come out as None on the terminal and therefore cant be added to any file because it simply crashes. how coudl i make it ignore the empty tags ?

Comment: Yea thats what im looking to solve

Comment: What do you mean it crashes? What line? I assume your console shows an error? Is there a stack trace present?

Comment: you see in the wiki_spider() last loop the 3 commented out lines, the last one returns this error when i put it in the code and try to make it write the text it pulls out in a txt file.

TypeError: must be str, not None

Comment: the 2 other lines above were an attempt to fix the problem

Comment: I do a similar things, however I do not open the file till after. 

`if words.string is None:
    print("IM GETTING EMPTY")
else:
    #write to your file here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my preemptive answer, which may change as I get more information.

My assumption is that your problem about the empty tags making the program crash stems from this line:

`words = words.string`

Because the property `string` may not be present on `words` if the tag is empty.

Try this:

```
        for words in soup.findAll('p'):
            word = words.string
            if word != "\n":
              wordlist.write(word)
            print(word)
```

I am not sure what `word` may equal (whether or not it will actually be `"\n"` in the case that the tag is empty, or if you want to check whether the trimmed string version of the content is `""` or what have you), but the idea remains: you only want to write the word if it exists.

The question you proposed was to skip `<p>` tags, but maybe you can still have your desired behavior through a different solution... by simply only writing to the file if the content is *not* empty.

**To answer your question about looping...**

I'm not sure it's a good idea that you would want to have your program constantly querying that server over and over and over again, with the only way of stopping it being a keyboard interrupt. But if you must... you should just be able to call it recursively:

def wiki_spider():
  # all your code, and then...
  wiki_spider()

You don't even need a `start()` method anywhere. You can just call `wiki_spider()` within itself (this is called recursion).

Like I said, though, that smells funny. Just remember to hit `ctrl + c` to stop your program before your computer explodes (exaggerating, but you get the point).

Comment: hahaha yea i will not spam wikipedia for endless hours, im just trying this as an exercice of the mind. I woudl probably have it query X number of times and than shutdown. but for now i just want it to run.

For the solution you offered, that precise solution did not work, it still returns the same error, but i do understand what you mean by going the other way around, ill look into that. Thanks so much !

Comment: @Ronin825 yeah I figured the precise solution wouldn't work, since I don't know what the `words.string` will return when the tag is empty, but conceptually, all the solution does is choose *not* to write to the file... it doesn't try to "skip over" any empty tags.

Comment: @Ronin825, and you're welcome! Hopefully this gets you another step closer.

Comment: Once thats taken care of. On to parsing all thoses paragraphs in singles words and making the program check to make sure i dont have them twice. What a headbagning moment this will be haha

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the badly called recursion and the filewrite:

try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
while True:
    sourcepage = requests.get(url)
    plaintext = sourcepage.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
    for words in soup.findAll('p'):
        word = words.string
        if word is None:
            print("NO WORD")
        else:
            print(word)
```

This will "filter" empty tags and print "NO WORD" which you can replace with 'pass'

inside the else statement you will have valid text.